# pandas series add previous row if diff negative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a df that contains some revenue values and I want to interpolate the values to the dates that are not included in the index. To do so, I am finding the difference between rows and interpolating:

```
rev_diff = df.revenue.diff().fillna(0)
df = df.resample("M").mean()
df["revenue"] = df.revenue.interpolate().diff()
```

I have this in a function and it is looped over thousands of such calculations (each one creating such a df). This works for most cases, but there are a few where the 'checkout till' resets and thus the diff is negative:

```
            revenue
2015-10-19  203.0
2016-04-03  271.0
2016-06-13  301.0
2016-06-13  0.0
2016-09-27  30.0
2017-03-14  77.0
2017-09-19  128.0
2018-09-19  0.0
2018-03-19  10.0
2019-03-22  287.0
2020-03-20  398.0
```

The above code will give out negative interpolating values, so I am wondering whether there is a quick way to take that into account when it happens, without putting too much toll on the execution time because it's called thousands of times. The end result for the revenue df (before the interpolation is carried out) should be:

```
            revenue
2015-10-19  203.0
2016-04-03  271.0
2016-06-13  301.0
2016-09-27  331.0
2017-03-14  378.0
2017-09-19  429.0
2018-03-19  439.0
2019-03-22  716.0   
2020-03-20  827.0
```

So basically if there is a 'reset', the diff should be added to the value in the row above. And that will happen for all rows below.

I hope this makes sense. I am struggling to find a way of doing it which is not costly computationally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the revenue of `2017-03-14` not 378? I don't understand why a reset is happening when 77.0 > 30.0 (previous revenue).

Comment: And I think such identification of reset using running difference would be too unreliable for production use when large data gaps or large revenue variations are present. For example: `2016-04-01 = 50.0` followed by `2017-03-25 = 70.0`. Is there a reset in between? From business logic there is likely, but from data you cannot tell.

Comment: Hi @BillHuang, you are right in the 2nd comment, I missed adding a couple of rows indicating the resetting of the revenue. Say that they happen at the same day that the previous revenue is logged. I edited the 1st dataframe. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You still didn't explain the 1st comment. `2017-03-14 = 408` does not match the rule you stated in the title.

Comment: ooops, you are right. I created the df quickly and didn't notice that I am not adding the diff. The `2017-03-14` revenue WILL be 378, then 429 etc. Thanks @BillHuang!

Comment: You seem to still got a typo: `2018-09-19` -> `2017-09-19`. I assumed it is, and proceeded. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No magic. Steps:

1. Identify the breakpoints by computing revenue difference.
2. Populate the `revenue` values to be added for subsequent data.
3. Sum it up.
4. Remove duplicate records.

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# 1. compute difference
df["rev_diff"] = 0.0
df.loc[1:, "rev_diff"] = df["revenue"].values[1:] - df["revenue"].values[:-1]

# get breakpoint locations
breakpoints = df[df["rev_diff"] < 0].index.values

# 2. accumulate the values to be added
df["rev_add"] = 0.0
for idx in breakpoints:
    add_value = df.at[idx-1, "revenue"]
    df.loc[idx:, "rev_add"] += add_value  # accumulate

# 3. sum up
df["rev_new"] = df["revenue"] + df["rev_add"]

# 4. remove duplicate rows
df_new = df[["index", "rev_new"]].drop_duplicates().set_index("index")
df_new.index.name = None
```

### Result

```
df_new
Out[85]:
            rev_new
2015-10-19    203.0
2016-04-03    271.0
2016-06-13    301.0
2016-09-27    331.0
2017-03-14    378.0
2017-09-19    429.0
2018-03-19    439.0
2019-03-22    716.0
2020-03-20    827.0
```